# In C#, internal structs give compiler warnings

Tags: c#, struct, visual-studio-2013, compiler-warnings, internal

I have a C# class library project that needs structs within it, but should not be exposed to anything outside of it. Thus, I have created a struct using the internal keyword, as illustrated below:

```
internal struct MessageInfo {
     internal bool IsSticky;
     internal bool IsImportant;
     internal int MessageID;
     internal int AuthorID;
     internal int Sort;
     internal string Title;
     internal string Body;
     internal DateTime DisplayFromDate;
     internal DateTime DisplayToDate;
};
```

This compiles and runs fine, however Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate, if that matters) throws compiler warnings such as:

```
warning CS0649: Field 'VNCM4.AjaxPages.MessageInfo.IsSticky' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value false
```

I have found that if I change all instances of the 'internal' keyword to 'public', the warnings go away. However, I would rather not do this as it seems crazy to have to make it public just to suppress warnings.

Is this a bug in Visual Studio, or is there something I'm missing? I have tried searching for this exact question and have yet to find anything on it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you ever assigning to any of those fields anywhere in your project?

Comment: That type has no business being a `struct`.  Not only are mutable structs evil, but that type very clearly does not represent a single logical value.  It should unquestionably be a `class`.

Comment: As addition to the @Servy 's comment there is design guideline which states `struct should has an instance size under 16 bytes`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the structure is internal, and the value is never assigned to anywhere in the entire assembly, then the compiler *know* that the value is never used, and can display the warning you see.  If it's public then it's possible for other assemblies referencing this one (which the compiler of course can't know about) to write to that struct's fields, so even if this assembly doesn't write to it, the warning doesn't apply.

The compiler is only capable of being helpful and giving you this warning when the `struct` is `internal`.

Comment: That's the interesting thing though, I am using it within the library. I probably should have placed that  in the original question. Sorry about that. :/

Comment: @TravisVroman You're assigning values to that field?  (And not, say, one of the other fields in that type?)  If you are, then clearly the warning is wrong.  I rather doubt that that's happening.

Comment: Ugh, that's it. I just double checked and there is one of them that isn't showing a warning because it's being assigned to. Apparently I should step away for a bit. Thank you!